# Как сделать размытие только сверху?

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно добиться такого эффекта? Именно размытия(вверху) поверх картинки?
Спасибо

[image: css размытие только сверху]

Comment: Либо кинуть box-shadow с синего блока на картинку, либо использовать filter: blur() для блока, но первый вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: Online генератор градиентов на любой вкус http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 5):

Например так используя свойство `box-shadow`:

```css
.box {
  background: transparent url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472157510410-64a053cbc39f?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=376&h=564&q=80&cs=tinysrgb) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  background: #40a7f4;
  color: #fff;
}

.text p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 35px 15px rgba(64, 167, 244, 0.98);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
      consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
      Eaque, sed.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Или еще вот так используя свойство `filter: blur(Npx);` :

```css
.box {
  background: transparent url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472157510410-64a053cbc39f?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=376&h=564&q=80&cs=tinysrgb) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  background: #40a7f4;
  color: #fff;
}

.text p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    top: -30px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #40a7f4;
    /* box-shadow: 0px -10px 35px 15px rgba(64, 167, 244, 0.98); */
    -webkit-filter: blur(11px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
      consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
      Eaque, sed.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Не совсем хорошие решения, `blur` тяжеловесный, `box-shadow` будет генерирует слишком много (4 стороны + углы) на таком большом блюре это хорошая нагрузка, лучше использовать линейный градиент.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен в правильности решения, но может быть подтолкнет вас на мысли.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}
img { 
  display: block;
}
.content {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,150,150,0.1), rgba(0,150,150,1) 25%); 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.time {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.greenrussia.ru/decor/uploads/posts/foto-yaponskogo-sada.jpg">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="time">5 days</div>
  </div>
</div>
```